# Travel in the Schengen area with a residence permit but no passport

Tags: schengen, germany, spain, eu, german-residents

We live in Germany and have residence permits (Aufenthaltstitel). Unfortunately, my wife lost her national passport. She applied for a new one, the process will take about three months.

Now, we need to travel to Spain. I am aware that the residence permit itself is not sufficient to travel even within the EU. This is sometimes checked by the airline companies.

My question is: if we decide to go for it (flying to Spain with the residence permit and copy of the passport only), what are the possible consequences?

- She is denied boarding the flight from Germany. That only means she doesn't go anywhere.
- She is denied boarding on our way back. This is more problematic, but we could try to book the next flight to check out luck. Otherwise, we can go back by train/car.
- She is controlled by police (be it Spanish or German on our way back). Here I'm not sure what happens. In theory, she can easily prove her ID (residence permit + scan of the pass), but in the worst case, what will happen? Will she be deported to Germany or to her home country?

The most important question is, will she be able to come back to Germany and is there any risk that she loses her residence permit?

Comment: Does she have a national ID card? Can she get an emergency passport?

Comment: She has (a Russian equivalent) of the national ID card, it would be a great idea to take it with us. It will serve as an additional prove of identity, but it won't make her travel legal I think. As for the emergency passport, our country doesn't issue those :(

Comment: Is the copy a simple photocopy or does it carry a stamp from e.g. the German police or your country's consulate in Germany?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is a simple photocopy. We will try to get a stamp on it, but I doubt they are going to make it official :(

Comment: That's confusing. You say your "Reisepass" (German document) was lost. And you say there is no emergency passport. There are at least *three* emergency variants, including (but not limited to) the express treatment at the Bürgeramt, the "vorläufiger Reisepass" from the Bürgeramt and the "Pass-Ersatz" from the federal police which you could even get at the airport if you have other papers to id you and the passport got lost or stolen right before your trip. So something does not add up in your question. Can you clarify which document you need and why there is no emergency variant available?

Comment: @nvoigt: I think what he means is that she lost her passport of the country she is a citizen of (Russia, presumably), not of Germany. If she had a German passport, there would be no need for an Aufenthaltstitel.